# How to access Django form field for validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to make validation methods on my Django form. by this I can validating easily through the Form instance

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=255)
password1 = forms.CharField(label='password', max_length=255, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
password2 = forms.CharField(label='retype password', max_length=255, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

def validate_password(self):
    if self.password1 == self.password2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def save(self):
    Account.objects.create(
        username=self.username,
        password=self.password1
    )
    print('${self.username} has been added!')
```

by that I can use the form on my view like this

```
post = request.POST
form = SignupForm()

if Account.objects.filter(username=post['username']).count() > 0:
    messages.warning(request, "account with the same username is already exists!")
    print("account saved")
else:
    if form.validate_password():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Account has been added")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "passwords don't match! {} {}".format(post["password1"], post["password2"]))

return redirect("signup")
```

I got an error in CLI like this

```
AttributeError: 'SignupForm' object has no attribute 'password1' [18/Aug/2020 16:10:10] "POST /accounts/signup HTTP/1.1" 500 74586
```

I think it refers the `if self.password1 == self.password2:` line

My error on my django response
[django error site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNRgP.png)

But it seems like I got an error that the form doesn't have the attribute that I have assigned when creating the model. is there a way I can access the object instance's attribute in the form method? This is my first python project so I have not mastered the language yet

OS: Windows 10
Django: 3.1
python: 3.7.4

Comment: check your indentation in the SignupForm class, unless you "mis-copied" your code that could be the problem

Comment: @LorenzoPaolin I'm confident  my indentation is already correct because the error only appears when I use my custom method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I made a mistake of not populating the form SignupForm() in line `form = SignupForm()` .So what I had to do is to assign it by `form = SignupForm(post)` in my view.

And I can access the form attribute by calling `self.data['username']`, not `self.username` in the form instance method.

the answer is that to access the form's instance fields is by using `self.data`, not call it directly the Django's Field